# Android - Tab items are not being created

Tags: android, tabs

I' am following a tutorial learning how to do a tab layout. I don't know what I did in the following code that it doesn't output the tabs. When the app runs, I don't see the tab item. Everything else works.

**Acitvity**

```
public class dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabs;
    ViewPager container;

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(container);
        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                container.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                container.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                container.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dashboard, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private String fragments [] = {"Completed", "In Progress"};
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    return new dashboard_completed();
                case 1:
                    return new dashboard_in_progress();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragments[position];
        }
    }
}
```

**dashboard_in_progress**

```
public class dashboard_in_progress extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_in_progress, container, false);
    }
}
```

**dashboard_completed**

```
public class dashboard_completed extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_completed, container, false);
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabs">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <view
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="android.support.v4.view.ViewPager"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: The code looks OK. Can you post the XML code for the respective layout, maybe the error is inside your XML code?

Comment: Is it possible that the tabs are there, but they just don't have text?

Comment: please also post the code of `SectionsPagerAdapter`.

Comment: what is `dashboard_completed();` and `dashboard_in_progress();`

Comment: you most to add tab in onCraete()

Comment: The code look perfectly OK. try to use that `PlaceHolderFragment` instead of `dashboard_completed` to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem.

```
ViewPager container;
...

private ViewPager mViewPager;
...

tabs.setupWithViewPager(container);
```

You're declaring two `ViewPager`s, but you're only initializing one, and trying to setup the `TabLayout` with the null one.

Remove the `ViewPager container;` declaration, and change the setup call to:

```
tabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Also, you don't need to set the `OnTabSelectedListener` on the `TabLayout` yourself. The `setupWithViewPager()` method will handle that for you.

Comment: Oh my god, you are my hero thanks bro, I' am trying this since past 8 hours.

Comment: Hey, no problem. I didn't see it until I was copying/pasting your code to run it myself. It would've been easy to spot if `TabLayout` would throw an Exception if you pass it a null `ViewPager`, but _c'est la vie_. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

there is no tab to show. use this :

```
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
```

Comment: `tabs.setupWithViewPager(container)` - The tabs should be coming from the `PagerAdapter`, not added manually.